# How do I get Ubuntu terminal prompt in Windows 7 with VMware Player

Tags: windows

I installed VMware Player on my Windows 7 PC. Now I downloaded ubuntu (ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso) software from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop .

I installed ubuntu via the instruction at http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11287/how-to-run-ubuntu-in-windows-7-with-vmware-player/ .

It is version Ubuntu 12.10. Now I have the ubuntu installed and it shows up in the left corner when I double-click on VMWare Player icon.

How do I get the UNIX like prompt in ubuntu here? I tried all icons but I find no ways. The documentation in the above link shows there are "Applications" ->"Accessories"->"Terminal" menus that takes it to the UNIX like terminal. But I do not see such options.

I anticipated something was wrong and I reinstalled ubuntu and that gives the 2nd ubuntu(2) icon in the VMWare screen.

When I double-click "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu(2)", I get the other screen (E2.jpg). Could you let me know how I get to the terminal? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of the VMware window with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, you can press that fancy button in the top corner (lens?) and type "terminal" (that's how you find things in Unity, the "applications ► accessories" things are for the older GNOME I think)

and might be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> (7 is the graphical interface), but I doubt that last one will work in a virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you so much.But ctrl-alt-t or ctrl-alt-1 to ctrl-alt-6 did not do anything on the screen. Do I need to install Vmware Tools for this? I think the Vmware tools were not installed during the first installation.

Comment: about the number shortcuts: I think that only works on an actual device. My VM doesn't do this on virtualbox at least, but if I boot in Ubuntu it does work. Ctrl-alt-t is a shortcut that should work, but maybe the ctrl is captured by the VM as the 'host' key or something?

Comment: Thanks again. Besides shortcuts do not work, I do not see the fancy button in the top corner (lens?) where I could type "terminal".

Comment: but what do you see then? You reference some screenshot, but I don't know where you put them. Basically: you'll have some sort of bar on the left with the top button having de ubuntu logo. That's thw one you need. Or are haven\t you even started the VM yet?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here I cannot attach a screenshot. I have uploaded the screenshots at http://bit.ly/ZqAGD7 . I removed Ubuntu 12.10 and installed the previous version 12.04 (ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) and ended up with the identical screens. Could you please let me know if my screenshots somewhere have the "top button having de ubuntu logo" that you referenced above? Yes I started VM. Thank you.

Comment: @Jay Please try to click inside the VM window. In this case the guest system should take control for your mouse/keybord.
Then follow the steps that Nanne suggests.